# How to disable "expand" from AppBarLayout in fragment that has a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library

I have two problems:

1) I was able to prevent the "expand" feature when i have no NestedScrollView inside my fragment, but when i do, it keeps expanding, even using:

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
appBarLayout.setActivated(false);
```

**There's any way to prevent the expanding of toolbar when i have a NestedScrollView inside a fragment?**

2) Even if i don't have a NestedScrollView, i'm still able to expand it when i touch my finger in the toolbar, and scroll down and up. The "expand & collapse" still works.

**How can i disable the action of collapse and expand the toolbar when i touch my finger in it and scroll down and up?**

Thanks.

Edit1 (More info):

This is the code of my fragment, inside of the FrameLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>

        <TextView />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And this is my activity structure:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    ...

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Edit 2: Th only question left now is:
**There's any way to prevent the expanding of toolbar when i have a NestedScrollView inside a fragment?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've faced with this problem not so far, and resloved it by changing `AppBarLayout` **height** when I need it be collapsable or expandable. So, **firstly**, you need to define the next two items in your default `dimens.xml` file:

```
<dimen name="toolbar_height">56dp</dimen>
<dimen name="toolbar_expanded_height">256dp</dimen> // this can be whatever you need
```

And then the complete method to prevent `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` from expanding/collapsing is:

```
public void disableCollapse() {
    appbar.setActivated(false);
    //you will need to hide also all content inside CollapsingToolbarLayout
    //plus you will need to hide title of it
    backdrop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    shadow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(false);

    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
    p.setScrollFlags(0);
    collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
    collapsingToolbar.setActivated(false);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbar.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
    appbar.requestLayout();

    //you also have to setTitle for toolbar
    toolbar.setTitle(title); // or getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

You may also **need to add status bar height** to toolbar's height, **if** you use `fitsSystemWindows=true` for example, so then you need to change

```
lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
```

to

```
lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_height) + (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? getStatusBarHeight() : 0);
```

And `getStatusBarHeight()` method implementation is:

```
protected int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And, **finally**, if you want to make your `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` collapsable/expandable again, you have to use next method:

```
public void enableCollapse() {
    appbar.setActivated(true);
    collapsingToolbar.setActivated(true);

    //you will need to show now all content inside CollapsingToolbarLayout
    //plus you will need to show title of it
    backdrop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    shadow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(true);

    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
    p.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
    collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(p);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbar.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_expanded_height);
    appbar.requestLayout();

    //you also have to setTitle for toolbar
    toolbar.setTitle(title); // or getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey rom4ek, thanks for the answer. When i applied your solution two things happenned: 1) My title was gone. 2) Even if i put this in a postDelayed, to execute after the toolbar is collapsed, the image from toolbar is showing again, but only with the height i specified.

Comment: Hey, I totally forgot some things: 1) You will need to renew the title each time you disable/enable collapse + you also have to handle collapsingToolbar title enabled/disabled. 2) You need to hide/show all content inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` according to disabling/enabling collapsing. Check my edited methods to enable/disable collapsing, please.

Comment: Hey rom4ek, we are almost there. The behavior that is happening now when i'm using disableCollapse method is: the toolbar is being invisible, then is being visible again, cousing a poor user experience. You can simulate what i'm saying scrolling the content to the bottom, then replace the fragment. Apparently, the toolbar stays with 0 height, to only then be what i specified.

Comment: Ok, i was able to handle this with postDelayed. I will accept your answer, but i really hope they implement something elegant to handle these cases hehe

Comment: Hm, I didn't face with that problem, though I was using it with fragments as well. Glad you resolved it, and thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 5):

To block the scrolling with your finger over the `AppBarLayout` you must use the `DragCallback` interface:

```
AppBarLayout layout = ...;
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

<strike>To prevent the `AppBarLayout` from scrolling due to `NestedScrollView` scrolling, you must remove the behaviour from `NestedScrollView`:</strike>

```
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = ...;
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) nestedScrollView.getLayoutParams();
params.setBehavior(null);
```

Another thing you can try is to remove the scroll flags from the AppBarLayout childs:

```
AppBarLayout layout = ...;
View child = layout.getChildAt(0);
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);
```

Comment: Hi natario, thanks for your answer. The first part worked for me! I can control when the touch will work. Now, the second part. The thing is, My NestedScrollView is not directly inside of the CoordinatorLayout. I have to use a FrameLayout inside of the CoordinatorLayout to manage the Fragment replacements. And the FrameLayout has no such method as setBehavior. Any solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Replace NestedScrollView in my example with the direct child of Coordinator. There must be in your layout a direct Coordinator child that has scrolling_view_behavior. You must remove that behavior, with the code I posted.

Comment: Didnt worked.. I've editted my question with some more information. I've put a behavior in the FrameLayout to work as i wanted before this problem, maybe i did wrong? Should i use different?

Comment: Just some more information, when i removed the behavior from my FrameLayout, the collapsingtoolbar now is above my framelayout when i scroll down.

Comment: You are right, my answer is wrong. Try `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(frameLayout, false)` (on the frame layout), or, if that doesn’t work,  `nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` (on NSV). Leave the behaviour as is.

Comment: Sorry :-) don't know then!

Comment: Another thing you could try is remove the scroll flags from the AppBarLayout childs.

Comment: It's locked now, but the Toolbar is expanded. I need it collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

in your specific fragment onViewCreated method add

```
 private void disableCollapsing() {
    AppBarLayout layout = ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).appBarLayout;
    View child = layout.getChildAt(0);
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(0);
}
```

and reActive collapsing when destroyed

```
private void enableCollapsing() {
    AppBarLayout layout = ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).appBarLayout;
    View child = layout.getChildAt(0);
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    params.setScrollFlags(1);
}
```